# ASP.NET Core: validating Auth0's JWT token

Tags: c#, .net-core, jwt, token, auth0

I'm using Auth0 and parsing its `idToken` server-side like this:

```
    var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
    var jwtToken = tokenHandler.ReadJwtToken(idToken); // idToken comes from client using auth0.js
    var sub = jwtToken.Claims.First(claim => claim.Type == "sub").Value;
```

The above code works well and I'm able to parse the `idToken` successfully, but I'd like to validate the `idToken` before trusting it, so I've tried this:

```
        string clientSecret = "{client_secret}"; // comes from Auth0 application's client secret
        var validations = new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            ValidateIssuer = true,
            ValidateAudience = true,
            ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
            ValidIssuer = "some value", // used "iss" from here: https://jwt.io/
            ValidAudience = "some value", // used "aud" from here: https://jwt.io/
            IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(clientSecret)),
        };

        var principal = tokenHandler.ValidateToken(idToken, validations, out var validatedToken);
```

When trying to validate the token, it results in this exception:

```
Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SecurityTokenSignatureKeyNotFoundException
  HResult=0x80131500
  Message=IDX10501: Signature validation failed. Unable to match key: 
kid: '[PII is hidden. For more details, see https://aka.ms/IdentityModel/PII.]'
```

I grabbed the issuer and audience values by parsing one of the tokens here: https://jwt.io/. The client secret is my application's client secret at Auth0.

How can I validate Auth0's `idToken` using `JwtSecurityTokenHandler`?

Comment: Interesting article here https://www.jerriepelser.com/blog/manually-validating-rs256-jwt-dotnet/

Comment: @Nkosi that's exactly what I was looking for. Can you post that link as an answer? I'll mark it as the correct one. Thanks!

Comment: I would suggest add what you got to work as a self answer and reference the article to help others who may have this problem in the future.

Comment: @JohnnyOshika - would be happy if you can update how you resolved this
As I understand it, you should find a way to set the "issuerSigningKey" of Auth0 and then "ValidateIssuerSigningKey" should work

Comment: @TGN12 See my answer below...

Answer (score 1):

To manually validate Auth0's JWT token, you need these 2 Nuget packages:

```
System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt
Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect
```

Then get these values from Auth0's application settings

```
string auth0Domain = ""; // Note: if your Domain is foo.auth0.com, this needs to be https://foo.auth0.com/
string auth0ClientId = "";
```

Validate Auth0's token as follows:

```
IConfigurationManager<OpenIdConnectConfiguration> configurationManager = new ConfigurationManager<OpenIdConnectConfiguration>($"{auth0Domain}.well-known/openid-configuration", new OpenIdConnectConfigurationRetriever());
OpenIdConnectConfiguration openIdConfig = await configurationManager.GetConfigurationAsync(CancellationToken.None);

var validations = new TokenValidationParameters
{
    ValidIssuer = auth0Domain,
    ValidAudiences = new[] { auth0ClientId },
    IssuerSigningKeys = openIdConfig.SigningKeys
};

var user = tokenHandler.ValidateToken(idToken, validations, out var validatedToken);
```

With the validated token, you can extract useful info like this:

```
var securityToken = (JwtSecurityToken)validatedToken;
var userId = user.Claims.First(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value;
```

Source: [Manually validating a JWT using .NET](https://www.jerriepelser.com/blog/manually-validating-rs256-jwt-dotnet/)

Credit: @Nkosi

Comment: Why do it manually and not use "ValidateIssuerSigningKey" ?

Comment: This is dating back a year, but I think it was because I couldn't get `ValidateIssuerSigningKey` to work. See my original question above.